# Could you print the variable name in a Groovy list and not the value

Tags: list, dictionary, groovy

If I got a list in Groovy containing 2 or more variables with some value, and I want to see if it contains a given text string I'm doing the following:

```
def msg = '''
 Hello Mars!
'''

def msg1 = '''
 Hello world!
'''


def list = [msg, msg1]

list.findAll { w -> 
    if(w.contains("Hello"))
    {
        println w
    }
    else
    {
        println "Not there"
    }
}
```

But instead of printing the value I would like to print the variable name that contains the text. Is that possible with a list or do I need to make a map?

Comment: `each` is probably better than `findAll` in this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a `Map`, because mapping from keys to values.

```
def msg = '''
 Hello Mars!
'''

def msg1 = '''
 Hello world!
'''

def map = [msg: msg, msg1: msg1]

map.findAll { key, value -> 
    if (value.contains("Hello")) {
        println key
    }
    else {
        println "Not there"
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so I need to use a Map, and map them to them self? I was hoping there was a Name method or something like that.

Comment: @Nyegaard no, Strings, ints, etc do not remember their name at declaration.  Can't think of any language where they do...

Answer (score 4):

If you are running this as a Groovy script, you may use the [`binding`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Script.html#getBinding%28%29) <sup>[archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150317015016/http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Script.html)</sup> instead of a list of variables, but you need to assign the variables without the `def` (so they become part of the binding). Something like:

```
aaa = 'Hello World!'
bbb = 'Goodbye all!'
ccc = 'Hello Mars!'

this.binding.variables.each { var ->
    if (var.value ==~ /Hello.*/)
        println "$var.key contains 'Hello'"
}
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/kUtwA):

```
aaa contains 'Hello'
ccc contains 'Hello'
```